Is there a way to know until what time a point-in-time recovery of an Oracle database was performed?
Is there a way to know until what time a point-in-time recovery of an Oracle database was performed?
I only found references to the columns RESETLOGS_CHANGE# and RESETLOGS_TIME in V$DATABASE, but these times do not necessarily indicate up to which moment the recovery was performed, but rather when the database was opened with the open resetlogs.

Check the SYS audit trail for the specific restore commands.

do you mean audit trail or /u01/app/oracle/admin/$SID/adump?

the SYS audit entries are generally written to the file system, though it may depend on your specific instance and version of Oracle.
